# Update Gradle project libraries

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle

I have added web dependency by editing `build.gradle` file and adding line below in my Spring Eclipse Java project.

```
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
...
    }
```

But project complains `The import org.springframework.web cannot be resolved`. How to tell `Spring Tool Suite 4` project update this library?

UPD

My whole build.gradle :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.4.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '15'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

UPD 2

I have another project that was generated with web module from very beginning. I looked in project properties in both of them and found that current project don't have `Web App Libraries` :

[image]

Current project:
[image]

Should I ask gradle somehow update Spring Tool Suite project with required library?

UPD 3 Project file structure:

```
drwxrwxr-x 8 a a 4096 Oct  4 07:39 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 a a 4096 Oct  4 08:27 ..
drwxrwxr-x 5 a a 4096 Oct  1 08:18 bin
drwxrwxr-x 9 a a 4096 Oct  4 07:39 build
-rw-r--r-- 1 a a  599 Oct  4 05:32 build.gradle
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a 1102 Oct  1 08:18 .classpath
-rw-r--r-- 1 a a  397 Oct  1 07:54 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x 7 a a 4096 Oct  1 07:56 .gradle
drwxrwxr-x 3 a a 4096 Oct  1 07:54 gradle
-rwxr-xr-x 1 a a 5766 Oct  1 07:54 gradlew
-rw-r--r-- 1 a a 2763 Oct  1 07:54 gradlew.bat
-rw-r--r-- 1 a a  590 Oct  1 07:54 HELP.md
-rw-rw-r-- 1 a a  741 Oct  1 08:18 .project
drwxrwxr-x 2 a a 4096 Oct  1 08:18 .settings
-rw-r--r-- 1 a a   26 Oct  1 07:54 settings.gradle
drwxrwxr-x 4 a a 4096 Oct  1 07:54 src
```

Comment: What is type of Gradle (built-in Gradle inside Spring Tools Suite or stand alone Gradle installation? What is your operating system? Don't use Android Studio for Spring web application.

Comment: I'm using Spring Tools Suite and build in gradle in my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Built-in Gradle (inside IDE) or stand alone Gradle installation?

Comment: I'm using Built-in Gradle (inside IDE)

Comment: Do you see anything like Gradle wrapper (`gradlew`)? Let's take screenshot your directory structure of file/foder source code.

Comment: Yes, I see `gradlew`. I have adde file structure in UPD 3 in question body.

Answer (score 0):

did you also add

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

To your gradle build? The maven import needs to resolved from somewhere, maven central is a good place.
According to Spring you also need to use the spring plugin

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}
```

At the top of your build gradle

Comment: I added whole `build.gradle` file in question body and all items you mentioned exist. Maybe I need to run some command in order to update project?

Comment: You can try ```gradlew clean build```

Comment: I used android studio, in which you have a gradle sync. Don't know what the eclipse equivalent is. But it shouldn' t matter. Gradle can build without help of IDE's